# Git rebase a branch from a branch that's also been rebased

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, branching-and-merging

Let's say I have this situation where `branch1` was created from `master`. After a few commits on `branch1`, I also created another branch off of that called `branch2`. After this, someone else committed (D) in `master`. Now I want to rebase `branch1` with `master`. But what about `branch2` since `branch1`'s hashes have been rewritten and now `branch2` is lost.

```
master:  A - B - C - D
                  \
branch1:           E - F
                        \
branch2:                 G - H
```

After rebasing branch1 on top of master, branch2 is lost because rebasing rewrites the hash of branch 1.

```
master:   A - B - C - D
                       \
branch1:                E - F

branch2:                 G - H
```

Is there a proper way to use git rebase branch 2 on top of branch1 again in a situation like this?

Comment: **Update**: I saw this reddit comment in a similar situation, I feel like this'll work: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/lfv8yp/comment/gmsj4cb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve what you want with `branch2`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why not? This use-case is dealt with by using `git rebase --update-refs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`branch2` is *not* lost and your second ASCII art is not correct. After rebasing branch1, your history now actually looks like this:

```
master:   A - B - C - D
                   \   \
branch1:            \   E' - F'
                     \
branch2:               E - F - G - H
```

Commits `E` and `F` were not moved, but copies of the commits were created. `E` and `F` still exist exactly the same as prior to the rebase (commits can never be modified, once created). `G`'s parent still points to `F`, so `F` must exist.

With that cleared up, let's look at two answers how to get `G..H` onto `F'`:

1. `git rebase --onto "F'" F branch2`. Works with older Git versions and can be executed after branch1 has been rebased.
2. `git rebase --update-refs master branch2`. Only works with recent Git versions and must be done instead of rebasing branch1: it will rebase all commits while moving the refs, such as branches, to the new, rebased commits.

Comment: This is a really good explanation. Thank you [@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)!

Answer (score 0):

you can still rebase branch2 on top of the updated branch1 after you have rebased branch1 on master.
The key is to use git's reflog to locate the lost commit (H) in branch2 and then apply it on top of the new branch1.

**Rebase branch1 on top of master:**

**git checkout branch1**

**git rebase master**

This will replay the commits E and F on top of D:

```
master:   A - B - C - D
                       \
branch1:                E' - F'
```

**Now, let's restore branch2.**
Git's reflog keeps track of references and their previous states, including branches before they were rewritten. You can use the reflog to find the

**commit hash (H) of branch2:**

**git reflog branch2**

This will display a list of previous positions of branch2 along with their corresponding commit hashes. Look for the commit hash that points to the commit H.

**Create a new branch at the commit H**

**git checkout -b branch2_new <commit_hash_of_H>**

Now you have restored branch2 as branch2_new:

```
master:   A - B - C - D
                       \
branch1:                E' - F'
                             \
branch2_new:                  G - H
```

If branch2_new is the updated version of branch2 that you want, you can now delete the old branch2 and rename branch2_new:

**#git branch -d branch2
#git branch -m branch2_new branch2**

Now branch2 has been updated and is based on the latest branch1.

```
master:   A - B - C - D
                       \
branch1:                E' - F'
                             \
branch2:                      G - H
```

Remember that rebasing can cause confusion and potential conflicts, especially when multiple developers are working on the same branches. It's essential to communicate with your team to ensure a smooth rebase process and avoid disrupting others' work. Additionally, it's generally a good practice to only rebase feature branches (like branch1 and branch2) and avoid rebasing the main master branch, as it's considered a shared and stable branch.

Comment: Why not use `git rebase --update-refs`?

Comment: I don’t see the point of using the reflog here.

Comment: this does not rebase G and H on top of E' and F' you need to run `git rebase --onto branch1 G^ branch2_new` to do that... stilll no need for the reflog...

Comment: Your answer is flat out wrong and makes no sense. There is no need to go to reflog. See the other correct answer.